# How do proponents of the New Natural Law Theory (NNLT), such as John Finnis & Germain Grisez, define natural law?

Tags: philosophy-of-law, aquinas, natural-law

I looked in the main books of NNLT, namely *Natural Law and Natural Rights* by John Finnis and [*The Way of the Lord Jesus*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=title:%22The%20Way%20of%20the%20Lord%20Jesus%22) by Germain Grisez, but I did not find a definition of natural law.

Comment: If they don't define it, then just look it up in a dictionary of philosophical terms and assume that's what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

Germain Grisez, [*The Way of the Lord Jesus* (vol. 1): *Christian Moral Principles*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7800), ch. 7 "Natural Law and the Fundamental Principles of Morality", § "Question A: What does ‘natural law’ mean in Catholic teaching?":

> 1. According to St. Paul, even the Gentiles find the requirements of morality which conscience
>    discerns written in their hearts. Although Gentiles do not have the law divinely revealed to the Jews,
>    they naturally do have this given standard of conduct (see [Rom 2:14–16](https://aquinas.cc/la/en/%7ERom.C2.L3)).<sup>1</sup>
> 2. The Church calls these naturally known principles “natural law.” They are natural in the sense
>    that they are not humanly enacted but are objective principles which originate in human nature […] Thus, in speaking of natural law, we are not contrasting “natural” meaning
>    “physical” with “intellectual.” As a matter of fact, natural law does pertain to intellect. Nor is the
>    contrast primarily that of “natural” with “supernatural,” for natural law overlaps divinely revealed
>    law.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1. See [C. Spicq, O.P.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DSpicq%2C%20Ceslaus%2C%20O.P.%22), *Théologie Morale du Nouveau Testament*, 14<sup>th</sup> ed., vol. 1 (Paris: J. Gabalda, 1970), 394–406.</sup>